# How can I use $_FILES in a Magento 2 way?

Tags: magento2, file-upload

I used `$_FILES` when uploading files, but `magento-connect` do not allow to use global variables, and it generates an error in the validation report:

> Direct use of $_FILES Superglobal detected

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I am using import feature in system configuration, then what will be the fileId value ? @Asif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same issue but a little search in the core and also this [link](http://blog.magestation.com/2016/03/how-to-fix-direct-use-of-files-superglobal-detected-ecg-magento2/) helped us figure out the solution

you've to use

```
$uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
  'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
  ['fileId' => 'my_file_uploader']
);
```

in place of $_FILES and it's much better like this, you can access various methods in the object. 
To check the output, use:

```
 var_dump($uploader->validateFile());
```

this will return an array with details about the file uploaded.

Hope it helps.

Comment: using OM directly like this is not a good idea. this can be done much simpler via the ui components, but maybe they weren't available when this answer was submitted

Comment: I am using import feature in system configuration, then what will be the fileId value ? @ClaudiuCreanga @R T

Comment: @KeyurShah if it is to upload a file in system config you can check this https://github.com/ClaudiuCreanga/magento2-store-locator-stockists-extension/blob/a7e4e2b20ec64b6aac8362ea6d2c76e63088ed87/src/Model/SystemImage.php if not maybe ask a question

Comment: Thanks a ton @ClaudiuCreanga It really helps me a lot to resolve the issue. :)

Comment: when we decide to not upload the image as its not mandatory it gives an exception, how can we validate before using above ?